# Is there a way to show a preview of a RecyclerView's contents in the Android Studio editor?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, android-tools-namespace

When I add the RecyclerView to the layout, it shows up as a blank screen.  Is there a way, such as through the `tools` namespace, to show a preview of the content of the RecyclerView?

Answer (score 717, accepted):

@oRRs is right !

I'm using Android Studio 1.4 RC2 and you can now specify any custom layout.

I tried a custom CardView and it works.

```
tools:listitem="@android:layout/simple_list_item_checked"
```

Comment: See @oRRs comment : tools:listitem="@android:layout/simple_list_item_checked"

Comment: is there any way to preview in grid mode?

Comment: @sajad try this
 app:layoutManager="GridLayoutManager"
 tools:listitem="@layout/layout_list_item_select_seat"
 app:spanCount="5"

Comment: Is there a way to show two types of items previewed. Sometimes RecyclerView shows more than one item Types.

Comment: For me i currently just have to write `tools:listitem="@layout/simple_list_item_checked"`

Comment: If you also wish to set the orientation to be horizontal , you can: `tools:orientation="horizontal"`

Comment: thank you! this has been an annoyance for me for a long time

Comment: In addition to specifying `tools:orientation="horizontal"` or `android:orientation="horizontal"` I also had to specify `app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"` as per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35681433/previewing-horizontal-recyclerview-in-android-studio

Comment: This is a pretty cool feature :-) I was wondering how would be the approach if the recycler view has different item types. Does anyone know?

Comment: is there anyway to use ItemDecorations .? like tools:ItemDecorations  something like this.?

Comment: Don't use camel casing for 'listItem'. It is 'listitem'.

Answer (score 174):

**Android tools and LayoutManager**

> `tools` namespace enables design-time features (such as which layout to show in a fragment) or compile-time behaviors (such as which shrinking mode to apply to your XML resources)
> It is really powerful feature that is developing and allows you not compile code every time to see changes

**AndroidX**[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58557614/4770877) and `GridLayoutManager`

```
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
```

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    tools:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager"
    tools:listitem="@layout/item"
    tools:itemCount="10"
    tools:orientation="vertical"
    tools:scrollbars="vertical"
    tools:spanCount="3"/>
```

**Support library** and `LinearLayoutManager`

```
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
```

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    tools:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
    tools:listitem="@layout/item"
    tools:itemCount="3"
    tools:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:scrollbars="horizontal" />
```

Another cool feature that was introduced in `Android studio 3.0` is predefining a data through the tools attributes, to visualised easily your layout structure using [`@tools:sample/*` resources](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/tool-attributes#toolssample_resources)

item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:background="@tools:sample/backgrounds/scenic">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        tools:text="@tools:sample/first_names" />

</FrameLayout>
```

**Simulator results:**

[image][image][image]

Comment: This should be marked as answer, as it is detailed and compatible with RecylerView. ListViews are not used at all nowadays.

Comment: I had to switch to fewer attribute tab in the attribute area to be able to see the `listitem` option, I could simply just type it into the xml code!

Comment: If you are using your own list item layout and you are only seeing one(1) list item then check that layout_height="wrap_content" on your layout.

Comment: Interistingly, it only works for me if I use ListView but not with a RecyclerView. Any ideas¿? I copy pasted to be sure I wasn't messing things up with my RecyclerView. But actually it works, so it is a valid XML.

Comment: "@tools:sample/*" is a reserver android resource type of placeholder data you can inject into your layouts. last_names - Common last names. The full official doc - https://developer.android.com/studio/write/tool-attributes#toolssample_resources

Answer (score 7):

First, add the following line in your item XML to made a preview of your list while you edit your item:

```
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_my_recyclerview_item"
```

And them, add the following line in your RecyclerView XML to preview how your item will look in your list:

```
tools:listitem="@layout/adapter_item"
```

Comment: showIn is very nice to use

Answer (score 4):

### If you have already a custom_item layout:

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
             android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
             ...
             ...
             **tools:listitem="@layout/name_of_your_custom_item_view"**
             ...>
</androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
```

Answer (score 3):

As of Android Studio 1.3.1 it shows default list items in the preview but it doesn't let yout specify your own yet. Hopefully, it will come.

Comment: In AS 1.4 you get to select from a few predefined layouts, e.g.: tools:listitem="@android:layout/simple_list_item_checked". Just right-click the RecyclerView in the layout editor and choose "Preview list content". Unfortunately, you still cannot use it for your own layouts, at least for me it's throwing a rendering error.