# Is it possible to show RecyclerView preview in layout editor with horizontal orientation?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

RecyclerView is shown with vertical orientation, and can not set this property, because orientation belongs to the `LinearLayoutManager` object. Any way to simulate HORIZONTAL layout?

Anyway the `linearLayoutManager` created in code is set to HORIZONTAL.

```
llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL);
```

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29929963/is-there-a-way-to-show-a-preview-of-a-recyclerviews-contents-in-the-android-stu

Answer (score 21):

try to add these parameters to your RecyclerView inside your layout xml:

```
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:scrollbars="horizontal"
  app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
```

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, there is no such facility editor provide yet.
although you can set the orientation of `LinearLayoutManager` Horizontal at runtime, this will fulfill your requirement.

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager
                = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
```

Comment: It does not work. Set to HORIZONTAL, but still layout editor show it as VERTICAL.

Comment: @János It should work can u post xml and java code here

Comment: @Dilip should not work in the preview editor,  that's what was asked, but it will in the device.

Answer (score 1):

RecyclerView won't show your actual data in the Editor Layout as the data you add in your RecyclerView is added **Dynamically** in your java code through Adapter and you implement a layout manager for your recyclerView in your java code and your Editor Layout displays the elements that are in your xml, so in your XML file its just a plain recyclerView which has no idea of what data is added in your Java implementation or what LayoutManager is to be implemented on it.