# Is there a way to show a preview of a RecyclerView's contents as Grid in the Android Studio editor?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

When I add the RecyclerView to the layout, it shows up as a list view in vertical order. I am using `tools:listitem` for this. Is there a way, such that it displays as grid but not as list in the Android Studio Editor?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

**This Worked for me (AndroidX):**
For 3 column grid

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rvServiceList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager"
    app:spanCount="3"
    tools:itemCount="20"
    tools:listitem="@layout/row_item_service" />
```

Answer (score 78):

**Android RecycrerView preview**

You are able to build a preview using `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"` namespace.

AndroidX[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58557614/4770877)

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    tools:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager"
    tools:listitem="@layout/item"
    tools:itemCount="7"
    tools:orientation="vertical"
    tools:scrollbars="vertical"
    tools:spanCount="4"/>
```

Support

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    tools:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager"
    tools:listitem="@layout/item"
    tools:itemCount="7"
    tools:orientation="vertical"
    tools:scrollbars="vertical"
    tools:spanCount="4"/>
```

From `Android studio 3.0` you can predefine a data through the  [`@tools:sample/*` resources](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/tool-attributes#toolssample_resources)

item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:background="@tools:sample/avatars">

    <TextView
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        tools:text="@tools:sample/first_names" />

</FrameLayout>
```

As a result your preview will look like

[image]

[[More examples]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49320755/4770877)

Comment: If you're using AndroidX, it's now `androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager` for the layout manager.

Answer (score 43):

If you want to see the effect only in the preview without change the app behavior you can use the "tools" namespace as you did with listitem:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rcv_collection"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager"
        tools:spanCount="2"
        tools:listitem="@layout/item_collection"/>
```

Answer (score 7):

Use

```
app:layoutManager="GridLayoutManager"
app:spanCount="3"
tools:listitem="@layout/table_grid_item"
```

Answer (score 5):

To show list horizontally in preview, just use these two attributes

```
tools:orientation="horizontal"
tools:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
```

here's the final code

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        ...
        tools:listitem="@layout/single_item_layout"
        tools:orientation="horizontal"
        tools:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager"/>
```

Comment: Was looking for grid, This is for horizontal list.

Comment: @AnandKumar see answer by alexpfx, just above me, he has mentioned how to show grid layout manager here is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47402709/4859873