# RecyclerView doesn't show up in Android Studio Preview

Tags: android, layout, android-recyclerview

This is what I am getting when I add a recyclerView in my layout.(I already imported the dependency)

My Layout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: RecyclerView in layout]

This is when I set height and width to wrap content:

[image]

Here I can't see the regular Recycler View like this:

[image]

So, how to get this view back on Android Studio?

Solutions tried so far;

1.Invalidate Caches

2.Delete the Caches folder in Android Studio 4.0 directory

Comment: Could you add to your question what you want to achive, please?

Comment: What version of RecyclerView are you using?

Comment: I am using version 1.1.0 .Now I have edited the question

Comment: please, check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45561951/is-there-a-way-to-show-a-preview-of-a-recyclerviews-contents-as-grid-in-the-and/47402709

Comment: Thanks  @AugustoCarmo for the link. I have already solved my issue by clean project .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Build > Clean Project** solved the issue.

Comment: I recommend trying that next time before resorting to Stack Overflow, it helps with a wide variety of issues.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion ! At first I tried the good old ,Invalidate Caches option and it didn't work (3 times) Then I deleted the cache and it didn't work also.Then,I tried to search on Google and SO ..but didn't find anything. Ultimately, clean project did the magic.

Comment: There's also this project https://github.com/rock3r/deep-clean, sounds fun, but never tried it.

Comment: It's seems like a game on Linux terminal.  LOL ... It may come handy for someone out there, but not for me, I guess!