# tools:listitem for custom view extending RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I try to use `tools:listitem` to show correctly styled sample-data on a `RecyclerView`. This works fine when using the original view.

But when **extending** `RecyclerView` to create my own custom view to add some functionality it just shows an empty space in the layout-preview in Android Studio.

How can I use all of the layout-preview stuff of a View when extending it?

My View looks like this:

```
class TestRecyclerView(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyle: Int
) : RecyclerView(context, attrs, defStyle) { }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The preview seems to work for other default-views, e.g. TextView (a custom-EditText renders just as a normal one). Maybe it's related to the implementation of the Design time attributes? E.g. they check for `RecyclerView` and not for `T extends RecyclerView`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
<com.test.my.TestRecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/your_id"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        tools:listitem="@layout/your_item"/>
```

**Don't forget to put a `app:layoutManager` attribute in your custom `RecyclerView`!**

```
app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
```

[image]

Comment: No sry, this does not work. When not built, the layout-preview shows a gray area with the name of the View in it. When built, it shows a white / empty area. As said, it seems to work for a simple extension of TextView (and maybe others) but not for `tools:listitem` on a extended `RecyclerView`. Or did this really work for you with my `TestRecyclerView`?

Comment: I am not able to get this working. I've created a blank demo-project (https://github.com/hardysim/custom-RecyclerView) to illustrate it. I've tested with Android Studio 3.2 stable and 3.3 Beta 3. Please have a look.

Comment: Ok !'m going to try it

Comment: I founded your problem. You have to put a `app:layoutManager` in your recyclerview ✔ (Updated post)

Comment: That's it. Good catch! Thx.

Answer (score 0):

**AndroidStudio listitem**

```
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
```

item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:background="@tools:sample/backgrounds/scenic">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        tools:text="@tools:sample/first_names" />

</FrameLayout>
```

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

    tools:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager"
    tools:listitem="@layout/item"
...
    >
```

[[Read more here]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49320755/4770877)